# find ontap position of an element inside a container in canvas flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

The point where I tap creates a line from the center to that point. But currently I can't get the coordinates of the tap that match the canvas coordinates. Is there any way to change the scaffold origin (0,0) and set its origin to the same as the container origin?
If bastman hits run then I want to show the direction where he/she runs with a black line.

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey _cardkey = GlobalKey();
  double posx = 100.0;
  double posy = 100.0;
  Size? cardSize;
  Offset? cardPosition;
  var height = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
  ui.Image? image;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    // print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
    print(posx);
    print(posy);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {getSizeAndPosition(); });
    loadImage('assets/images/wheel.png');
  }

  Future loadImage(String path) async {
    final data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final image = await decodeImageFromList(bytes);
    setState(() {
      this.image = image;
    });
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: Text("Canvas"),
        // ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.green),
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: GestureDetector(
              key: _cardkey,
              //   onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details){
              //  onTapDown(context, details);
              //  },
              onTap: (){},
              onPanStart: (details) {
                Offset position = details.localPosition;
                setState(() {
                  posx = position.dx;
                  posy = position.dy;
                });
                print(posx);
                print(posy);
              },
              onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                Offset position = details.localPosition;
                setState(() {
                  posx = position.dx;
                  posy = position.dy;
                });
              },
              child: FittedBox(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: image!.width.toDouble(),
                  height: image!.height.toDouble(),
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    // key: _cardkey,
                    painter: ImagePainter(posx, posy, image),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  double? posX;
  double? posY;
  ui.Image? images;

  ImagePainter(double posx, double posy, this.images) {
    posX = posx;
    posY = posy;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final CenterX = size.width / 2;
    final CenterY = size.height / 2;

    final paintCircle = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    // canvas.translate(size.width/2, -size.height/2);
    // canvas.scale(1,-1);

    final paintImage = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    // canvas.translate(size.width/2, -size.height/2);
    // canvas.scale(1,-1);

    final paintLine = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.width / 2, paintCircle);
    var circleCenter = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    var radius = size.width / 8;
    canvas.drawImage(images!, Offset(0, 0), paintImage);
    var line = canvas.drawLine(center, Offset(posX!, posY!), paintLine);
    //  print("$line");
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter olddelegate) => true;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a GestureDetector. It won't give you the position of a single tap. If you want the position of a onTap you need to use a `Listener`:

```dart
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (event) {
    setState(() {
      posx = event.localPosition.dx;
      posy = event.localPosition.dy;
    }
  }
),
```

The localPosition property should match the coordinates of the container IF you don't resize the child of the container. If they are not correct for some reason use `event.position` instead which will give you coordinates in the global coordinate space.

Comment: but i have resize tha child of container and want to match the coordinates from canvas coordinates to scaffold coordinates. is there any way to do this

Comment: > If they are not correct for some reason use event.position instead which will give you coordinates in the global coordinate space.